# Saving a string to HDFS creates line feeds for each character

Tags: scala, hdfs, apache-spark

I have a plain text file that I am reading from my local system that I am uploading to HDFS. I have Spark/Scala code that reads the file in, converts the file to a string, and then i use saveAsTextFile function to specify my HDFS path where I want the file to be saved. Note I am using the coalesce function because I want one file saved, rather than the file getting split.

```
import scala.io.Source

val fields = Source.fromFile("MyFile.txt").getLines
val lines = fields.mkString

sc.makeRDD(lines).coalesce(1, true).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://myhdfs:8520/user/alan/mysavedfile")
```

The code I have saves my text successfully to HDFS, unfortunately though, for some reason each character in my string has a line feed character after it.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get this working exactly as I wanted, but I did come up with a work around. I saved the device locally and then called a shell command through Scala to upload the completed file to HDFS. Pretty straightforward.

Would still appreciate if anyone could tell me how to copy a string directly to a file in HDFS though.